# I don't know where to start learning how a terminal emulator works

Tags: python, terminal, emulation, tty, pty

I'm an amateur programmer and I was trying to write my own terminal-based desktop environment in Python, but I don't know where to start learning how terminal emulators work. I have read some documentation but there are lots of concepts that I ignore. Could you give me advice about where to start, please?

Comment: "*I have read some documentation but there are lots of concepts that I ignore*" - If you're trying to learn how terminal emulators work based on their documentation, I can't imagine there are very many (if any) concepts covered in documentation materials that you could skip over and still have a full understanding.

Comment: Use the source, Luke. Read the source of a typical terminal emulator, like xterm, and see what is going on.

Comment: @esqew Sorry, my skills in English aren't that good. With "ignore" I meant that I don't know their meaning, not that I skip them.

Comment: That are many questions at once - first try to understand what a most basic dumb terminal in the 70s was about (e.g. an input line from keyboard, an output line for display text in a cursor grid driven fashion). Next try to understand how that links to a PTY nowadays (read/write on master side). That are the rough basics. Next look up VT100 spec to get a basic understanding of typical terminal functions and their behavior (see https://vt100.net). Implement that and you have a VT100 emulator.